# Recursively looping through text

Tags: python, recursion

I need to make a function that takes a text string of random characters, put lower case ones together, puts upper case ones together and throws the rest of the characters away. I have done an iterative solution to this, and this one works, but apparently it wasn't recursive - **I have to make it recursive**!

`check_lower`/`check_upper` are functions that check if a part of the string in `msg` contains lower characters or upper characters

```
def split_recursive(msg, low_msg='', up_msg=''):
    if not msg:
        return (low_msg, up_msg)
    if check_lower(msg[0]):
        low_msg += msg[0]
    if check_upper(msg[0]):
        up_msg += msg[0]
    return split_recursive(msg[1:], low_msg, up_msg)
```

An example string to look through would be

```
test = 'Jj9312L*xzc-,zt13_312GjASk3'
```

So in the end you would run

```
>>> split_recursive(test)
('jxzcztjk', 'JLGAS')
```

Comment: The code you've shown **is** recursive, so it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

For recursion, think about the base case:

```
def split_recursive(msg, lower, upper):
    if msg == '':
        return lower, upper
```

Then build it upwards:

```
def split_recursive(msg, lower, upper):
    if msg == '':
        return lower, upper
    else:
        if msg[0].isupper():
            return split_recursive(msg[1:], lower, upper + msg[0])
        elif msg[0].islower():
            return split_recursive(msg[1:], lower + msg[0], upper)
        else:
            return split_recursive(msg[1:], lower, upper)
```